# Update comma-separated column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server called `Settings` with a column `settingValue` which contains  comma-separated values.

Sample data for that column:

```
0, 0
US, US
test@test.com, test@test.com
```

I want to write an update query such that the column `settingValue` displays only one value that is it should result in

```
0
US
test@test.com
```

Not sure where to start shall I find comma (`,`) first and then truncate statement?

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in a column. Re-design your data model.

Comment: I am not storing i want to delete it someone else has entered those records duplicate

Comment: Those are 3 separate records

Comment: This design is not even in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF) - this indicates a bad relational model.

Comment: Don't use EAV data model then.  If you had data types you couldn't have an ID value of `0,0`

Comment: Its already existing table populated and designe i by someone i want  to delete those duplicate records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove everything after the first comma, then you can use:

```
update yourtable
set col = substring(col, 1, charindex(',', col)-1)
where charindex(',', col) > 0  -- only update the rows with a comma
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/196a4/1)

Comment: Or just start from 0 and no need for the -1 ?

Comment: @JodyT just a habit to start at 1. :)

Comment: I get this error when i tried
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: here is my query update [dbo].[settings] set settingKey = substring(settingKey, 1, charindex(',', settingKey)-1)

Comment: @user580950 see my edit to filter out any rows that do not have a comma in it